# values configuration qualifiers not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to set the dimensions for margins in dimensions.xml. So to have support for different screen sizes, I created folders like

```
    values
        dimensions.xml
    values-land
        dimensions.xml
    values-small
        dimensions.xml
```

But it doesn't seem to take values from the respective folders, for example, when in landscape mode, its not taking margin value from values-land folder.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you overriding configChanges in your manifest? If so, your activity will never be destroyed and recreated in landscape with the new values.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually the layout-land folder works perfectly but the values-land folder doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are your folders *actually* capitalized as shown in your code block above?

Comment: No..Sorry for that. I edited question.